# How do I get my Cordless Wheelmouse (MRF-2000) to work with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, wireless-mouse, ps2

The mouse came in two parts, one sender and one receiver. (I believe the data is radio transmitted) The receiver is plugged in with an PS/2 to USB adapter to my computer, and the other part is the mouse itself. In device manager my computer doesnt recognize the input;

[device manager - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQtVa.png)

[The mouse looks like this, but a different brand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDrEq.png)

So is it any way I could make this work or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Can you provide an English translation of the text on the line in Device Manager with the warning sign. Most of us can't decipher Swedish (or Norse, or Danish, whatever it is.) You can EDIT your own question to add that information.

Comment: @Tonny It is Swedish. "Okänd USB-enhet (begäran om enhetsbeskrivning misslyckades)" means "Unknown USB device (device description request failed)" if Google Translate is to be believed.

Comment: Yes G@Gantendo is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That MRF-2000 mouse is a standard PS/2 mouse from about the year 2000.
It should work with a PS/2 to USB adapter, but:

- the adapter needs to explicitly support PS/2 mice. (They also exist for keyboards and some adapters are keyboard only, others can do both and others are mouse-only.)
- The PS/2 to USB adapter has to provide power to the receiver plug. Many adapters don't do that.
- The PS/2 USB adapter has to be USB v2.0 or higher. Most modern USB3 ports can't fall back to USB v1.0 or v1.1 standard. (Some USB3 ports can't even do USB v2.0, but those are quite rare.)
- Or the receiver is just broken.
- Battery in the mouse is empty or too weak (these mice often don't like rechargeable batteries and need Alkalines.)

If this USB to PS/2 adapter has worked with this mouse on other computers in the past one of the last 3 points will most likely apply.
If you don't know if it ever worked it could be any (or several) of the 5 problems.
(The error-message isn't conclusive. Windows just says it notices something is there, but can't talk to it, which can be caused by all 5 issues.)

Getting a different adapter is just as expensive as getting a new USB mouse. And a different adapter is no guarantee it will work.

I wouldn't waste any time or effort on this and just get another mouse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, never used the mouse before (bought it second hand for almost nothing). It seems like a lost cause, might keep it as a collectors item then.

Comment: @Erik77 You should see my vintage collection :-) My oldest mouse is from 1981. A bus-mouse (with the original 8-bit ISA card) out of a first generation IBM PC. I still wish my father hadn't thrown away the PC itself in the late 90's. It would have been worth a pretty penny these days.